# Determine S3 file last modified timestamp

Tags: scala, playframework, amazon-s3

I have a `Scala Play 2` app and using [`AWS S3 API`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) to read from S3 files. I have a need to determine when the last modified timestamp is for a file, what's the best way to do that? Is it using `getObjectMetadata` or perhaps `listObjects` or ? If possible, I would like to determine the timestamps for multiple files in one call. Are there other open source libraries built on top of `AWS S3 APIs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A representation of S3 Object in AWS Java SDK is `S3ObjectSummary`, which has method `getLastModified`. It returns the modified timestamp.

Ideally just list all of the files using [listObjects](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest%29) and than call `getObjectSummaries` on a returned object.

Comment: Why wouldn't I just use `getObjectMetadata` instead of `S3ObjectSummary`?

Comment: Don't understand your question. `getObjectMetadata` is a method which return collection of `S3ObjectSummary` objects...